# FlashDevelop IDE compiles smaller swf than Flash Builder for identical actionscript project

Tags: flash, flash-builder, flashdevelop

Can anyone offer a clue as to why flashdevelop would compile to a smaller swf than Flash Builder?

The FD swf is 150k, FB swf is 220k.

I'm exporting as a release build in FB.

Comment: Quite a few possibilities. Open them in a swf-decompiler, or add a link to both of them, and because I'm bored research-wise, I'll put them through my homemade SWF parser and tell you the difference - and possibly a guess at the reason. Otherwise, add some more on the external resources the project references (fonts, images etc.) as well as what compiler FlashDevelop is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are referencing the exact same SDK file (not using the defaults SDK and are pointing both apps to the same SDK files), I would guess the compile arguments being passed to it are different.  The the default compiler options in the IDEs are probably different and would change the file size.  You can compare what options are set in FD and FB, but even the options they present are different.

In FB go to
Projects > Properties > Flex Compiler
You are given easy access to three check boxes and a space for adding your own arguments.

In FD (I am on an old version so this may have changed)
Project > Properties > Compiler Options
There is a much bigger list of compiler options you have easy access to and can add your own.

Sorry I can not give you more info on what the defaults for each actually are.